# How do I calculate average shortest path of a network in Neo4J using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 9 nodes in a directed network (all have at least 1 connection) so a total of 72 shortest paths. I want to find the average of the 72 shortest paths.

Here is the code I used to find all shortest paths between a set of nodes (modified from https://community.neo4j.com/t/all-shortest-paths-between-a-set-of-nodes/241)

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH collect(p) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as n
UNWIND nodes as m
WITH * WHERE id(n)<id(m)
MATCH path = allShortestPaths((n)-[:KNOWS*]-(m))
RETURN length(path)
```

The result at first looks to be correct. It has paths of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6. However, I noticed there are 408 results when there should only be 72.

Would appreciate any insight into where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The [allShortestPaths](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/all-shortest-paths-between-set-of-nodes/) function returns *all* shortest paths, so it can return multiple paths if they all have the same (shortest) length. To get just 1 shortest path, you should use the `shortestPath` function instead.
2. The number of *unique* pairs of nodes out of 9 nodes is not 9*8 (or 72). It is half of that, or 36.

This query should return 36 results:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH collect(p) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as n
UNWIND nodes as m
WITH n, m WHERE id(n)<id(m)
MATCH path = shortestPath((n)-[:KNOWS*]-(m))
RETURN length(path)
```

To get the average length, just use this `RETURN` clause instead:

```
RETURN AVG(length(path))
```

Comment: I see now. Thanks @cybersam